# javascript ecma5 overloading

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have a simple question, but i couldn't find the answer.

In ECMA5 javascript is there a way to method overload?

In this example I try to overload my ECMA5 class constructor, but it doesn't work.

```
function Classe1(arg1){
    console.log('OVERLOAD 1!');
}

function Classe1(arg1,arg2){
    console.log('OVERLOAD 2!');
}

var obj = new Classe1('arg1');
var obj = new Classe1('arg1','arg2');
```

When I run the code above it returns 'OVERLOAD 2' 2 times.

Comment: No, there's not. (And not in ES6 or later either).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found any question similar to mine, but there it is. Thanks again!

Comment: While technically overloading is not in JavaScript, because all arguments are optional in JavaScript, you can make a single method with all possible arguments and then within that function test to see which were passed. In that way, you can simulate overloading.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i did!